# Neighbors error "Erreur dans as.igraph.vs(graph, v) : Invalid vertex name(s) "

Tags: r, graph

Using a igraph graph, I have a data frame of nodes of graph g1,

```
DC1<-data.frame(
node=V(g1)$name,
Frequency=DC1$'DC')
DC2<-DC1[order(-DC1$'Frequency'),]
```

I use a loop, and at each step I take the first node of the data frame. For this node I calculate its neighbors, and after I delete it and its neighbors from the graph and from the data frame.

The problem is at some step I have this message `

Erreur dans as.igraph.vs(graph, v) : Invalid vertex name(s)`.`

When I try to know why, I find that at this step the algorithm can't read the first row of the data frame, so I can't get the neighbors to continue the process.

```
while(length(get.edgelist(g1))>0){

 v<-DC2$node[(order(-DC2$'Frequency'))]
 L<-V(g1)[V(g1)$name==v[1]]

 Nei <- neighbors(g1,L,1)

}
```

the problem is here :

```
 > v<-DC2$node[(order(-DC2$'frequency')) ]
   > L<-V(g1)[V(g1)$name==v[1]]
   > L
  Vertex sequence:
  [1] "125"
  > Nei <- neighbors(g1,L,1)
  > Nei
  numeric(0)
```

when i replace the `L` by its value, its works:

```
  > Nei <- neighbors(g1,125,1)
   > Nei
   [1]   28   30   76 1883
```

Comment: It seems `L<-V(g1)[V(g1)$name==v[1]]` is a character, not a number.

Comment: my graph has 4500 nodes, it works for other step, the error appears in the step of 2146 nodes. i don't think that the prob its in character or number, otherwise, it didn't run at the others iteration

Comment: this the dataframe that i have in return, the prob its just in finding the neighbors at this step, i dont know why?? Any help pleaase?? i am beginner in R
    1877  324       340
    1878  156         5
    1879  156       258
    1880  156       272
    1881  156       235
    1882  156       295
    1883  146        50
    1884  146       148
    1885  146       313
    1886  146       317
    1887  125      <NA>

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem is the as.igraph.vs() function. When you search for neighbours you call this function which forces R to treat what you have entered as an igraph object. The error comes up when you provide as an argument something that can't be converted into a vector(is not a character, logical, or an integer). You need to investigate exactly the type of the variable that you are passing to the function searching for neighbours as this is the source of the problem.

```
as.igraph.vs <- function(graph, v, na.ok=FALSE) {
  if (is.character(v) && "name" %in% list.vertex.attributes(graph)) {
    v <- as.numeric(match(v, V(graph)$name))
    if (!na.ok && any(is.na(v))) {
      stop("Invalid vertex names")
    }
    v
  } else {
    if (is.logical(v)) {
      res <- as.vector(V(graph))[v]
    } else if (is.numeric(v) && any(v<0)){
      res <- as.vector(V(graph))[v]
    } else {
      res <- as.numeric(v)
    }
    if (!na.ok && any(is.na(res))) {
      stop("Invalid vertex name(s)")
    }
    res
  }
}
```

This is from the igraph github, if you find it useful to read through this way.

I am not sure what `L` would be from looking at your code but that is the source of the problem.